# Python regex to split both on number and on capital letter

Tags: python, regex

I cannot get exactly what I want with regex
I have, for example a string

```
2000H2HfH
```

I need to get `['2000','H','2','Hf','H']`.

So, I need to split by number and by capital letter or capital following string

I use this `([A-Z][a-z]?)(\d+)?` and lose the staring number, which is understandable why, but I cannot get it back for the result to be readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\d+|[A-Z][a-z]*', text)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OmVM5E/1). Details:

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an upper case letter and then zero or more lowercase ones.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qp87ch):

```
import re
text = "2000H2HfH"
print( re.findall(r'\d+|[A-Z][a-z]*', text) )
# => ['2000', 'H', '2', 'Hf', 'H']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two capture groups one after another, so you capture them one after other. To achieve your goal you should modify your capture like this

```
([A-Z][a-z]?|\d+)?
```

Here the | symbol means that you capture capital letter following by lowercase letters OR number.

There is very nice service to compose and test regular expressions https://regex101.com/

Comment: also working, but Wiktor's regex returns clean list without trailing ' '